# Community in partial sandbox

Tags: community, sandbox

In December, I created a partial sandbox from production.  I have several Communities in production.  Today, I went to publish my community in the partial sandbox only to discover that there doesn't appear to be any communities associated with the partial sandbox.  I have been creating partial sandboxes for the past 3 years and have never seen something like this.  Of course today is the day that I really need to use the Community in the partial sandbox.  When I am in Setup, there isn't even options for Communities.  However, I can enable a contact for portal use.  When I click "Login to Community as User" I get an error that the URL no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a Spring '21 Preview Instance and didn't realize that the Community Setup label had been changed to Digital Experience.

Setup -> Feature Settings -> Digital Experiences -> All Sites.